# non indented lists with html

Tags: html, styles, semantics

I have a list of cities with additional information about a city.
I want to pin this cities on a map (an image) according to their position and I want to display the additional information if you hover a pin.

For the map of cities I would probably use `<map>` but it seems not to be intended to have code in `<area>`.
For the list of cities I would use a list. But lists seems to be meant to be indented always. And it seems to be very difficult to style them so the list points appear on the map.

So what do you actually use for this?

Edit: This is just an example and I do not want to use google maps or anything. I want to use HTML & CSS! It could also be persons on a family tree or stars in the sky or anything.

The thing is I have a list semantically, so I would use a html list, but I don't want it to be indented.

As my "accessibility" tag was removed without adding the information back here (thanks pal...): I want the page to be accessible by as many people as possible. So solutions that do not work on screen readers and so on do not work!

Comment: What's your question exactly? Your title and your question differs

Answer (score 0):

CSS defines a style attribute `z-index`. Elements with the lowest z-index go at the bottom, higher indexes overlap the lower ones. (Google for "CSS layers" for more info.)

So you could put the map image `<img>` at the lowest index, and position e.g. a text paragraph `<p>` or even `<a href>` for each city at consecutively higher indexes (because the city labels may overlap each other too).

You could then use a `onmouseover` action to display info for each city (Javascript etc.). But a much simpler way could be to use the `title` attribute of most HTML tags, which most browsers (as far as I am aware of) implement as at "tooltip" on mouseover. It's more basic, but may be enough for your application.

Comment: Try to view this in a screen reader. Sounds to be impossible to understand.

Comment: This is a very basic answer. If you don't use google maps, this is a good explanation. Check out some javascript libraries like jQuery. They can help you do what you want I guess.

Comment: @4485670, is it the answer or the original web page you want to view through a screen reader? I assume you mean the web page. Well, you didn't mention visual impairment in your question, and I agree: maps and mouseovers might not work well with screen readers. CSS overcomes the problem by allowing you to specify different styles for different `media types`, including `aural` and `braille

Comment: I tagged it with accessibility and thought that implied being able to read it in a screen reader. As google maps was mentioned here. I want something like google maps and the pins for specific points that overlay the map (if you search for something). But if you turn of the style in your browser this is not what I want ;)

Comment: I don't want to haggle but the accessibility tag covers a broad range of disabilities including deafness and paralysis (mouseover :-) the particular tag to see it). So perhaps you should define (write down) what behaviour you expect/want to cater for in your app in case a user is visually impaired. You know, as in a use case. Even if it is only for your own benefit, as I don't have experience developing such systems.

Answer (score -1):

FYI :

The [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=nl).

An [Article on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/default.asp) explaining the Google Maps API.

Plenty of information about this on [google](http://www.google.com?q=google%20maps%20API).

And how do you mean "lists seem to be indented always" ?
With a little bit of CSS you can do anything with HTML lists.

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

And the `<map>` element definition and usage is:

```
The <map> tag is used to define a client-side image-map. 
An image-map is an image with clickable areas. The required name attribute of 
the <map> element is associated with the <img>'s usemap attribute and creates a
relationship between the image and the map.

The <map> element contains a number of <area> elements, that defines the clickable
areas in the image map.
```

You can make `<area>` tags with php or any other server side language. But not sure if this aproach is easier than using Google Maps API :)

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear about it, see my edit. But google maps is not what I want.